# What hours are taxis available at Yangon Airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, myanmar

I will be traveling to Yangon, Myanmar in March.  My flight arrives at 10:50 pm on a Friday night.

I imagine it will take me some time to go through Customs and Immigration and gather my luggage, but when I leave the airport, I would like to get a taxi to my hotel.  I don't know how long all of this will take, but I would guess I may be leaving the airport around midnight.

**Will I be able to find a taxi from the Yangon (RGN) Airport late on a Friday night?**  Are taxis typically available at all times of the day or night from the Yangon Airport?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [reviews](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294191-i9454-k8958061-Transportation_Yangon_from_airport_late_at_night-Yangon_Rangoon_Yangon_Region.html) on Tripadvisor: **yes**, there are always taxis at Yangon airport:

> No problem at all, there's always Taxis - at night they're actually
>   even cheaper as there's less traffic (general rule in Yangon nowadays)
>   - 7000-9000 Kyat would be an acceptable price to downtown!
>
> If you use the Taxi booth mentioned by Dave, it's less hassle but
>   might be a little more expensive, if you (only if you have small
>   luggage) walk 1 minute just outside the airport gates and flag down a
>   Taxi there, it's gonna save you around 2000 Kyat usually :-)
>
> But definitely no problem at all to find transportation!

Since Yangon is Myanmar's most busy airport, I'd be very much surprised if there isn't at least one taxi driver all the time there.